# Нужно спроектировать uml-диаграмму web-сервиса. Я не понимаю включать ли сюда БД или отдельно делать?

Tags: веб-программирование, архитектура, uml

Мне посоветовали делать БД c помощью ORM. Но я не понимаю где идет граница между классами ORM и теми что не связаны с внесением изменений в БД. У кого есть опыт создания веб-сервисов, подскажите пожалуйста, как это должно работать!

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Если вам не ясно где провести границу, то покажите в своем вопросе, какие у вас есть компоненты, чтобы нам можно было казать, где ее проводить. Так же напишите, с какой целью вы эту границу хотите провести, так это важно. А еще неясно зачем вы создаете диаграмму, с какой целью, кто и как ею будет пользоваться? Цель диаграммы важна, чтобы понимать уровень детализации и что на ней отображать, а что упустить.